# Connection between Apache Httpd and Eclipse Tomcat (Windows 7)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

my purpose is to connect the httpd web server and the eclipse tomcat application server. I configured the tomcat server inserting in the server.xml the following line:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

I copied the mod_jk.so file into the httpd modules folder, I created into the conf folder the workers.properties file, which contains the following lines:

```
worker.list=myworker
worker.myworker.type=ajp13
worker.myworker.host=localhost
worker.myworker.port=8009
```

I added into the httpd.conf file the following lines:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
```

```
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogStampFormat "[%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S] "
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkLogLevel info

JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

Alias /testApacheTomcat "C:/Data/testApacheTomcat/"

<Directory "C:/Data/testApacheTomcat/">
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /*/WEB-INF/*>
    deny from all
</Location>

JkMount /testApacheTomcat/* myworker
```

and I started both Tomcat and Httpd.

Bot tomcat server and HTTPD are correctly started (if I ask for

```
http://localhost:8080/testApacheTomcat/
```

I see my app and if I ask for

```
http://localhost/
```

I see the HTTPD welcome page), but they don't communicate (if I ask for

```
http://localhost/testApacheTomcat/
```

I receive a 404 page not found). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the Alias and Directoy tags, this will be handled automatically. Therefore the Location tag is unnecessary too. Also add this line to you jk mounting:

```
JkMount /testApacheTomcat myworker
```

Then you shoul be able to access:

```
http://localhost/testApacheTomcat/
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, but now in my mod_jk.log file I have the line "
[Mon Oct 07 16:49:07.104 2013] [6648:8052] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized", and in my error.log file I have the line "[Mon Oct 07 16:49:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs/testApacheTomcat"

Comment: I removed the asterisk from the jkmount url. Does that solve the problem?